# SwingNode shows blank window on macOS with JDK 11.0.6 (and other) but not with JDK 11.0.2. Is there a workaround?

Tags: java, macos, swing, javafx

A swing component in an Java FX `SwingNode` does not show up if I use JDK 11.0.6, 11.0.7 or 13.0.2 on **macOS**. It does show up if I use JDK 11.0.2 or JDK 12.0.1 on macOS. It also works on other OSes.

**Is there a workaround?**

A corresponding project (MWE) illustrating the issue can be found at https://github.com/cfries/swingnodetest

You may run it using

```
git clone https://github.com/cfries/swingnodetest
cd swingnodetest
mvn compile exec:java
```

**Remarks:**

- The issue occurs with the code from the JavaDoc of SwingNode (appears to be not related to my coding). The code has been copied from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html
- The issue occurs with the latest version of JavaFX 11 in the Maven dependencies (`javafx-swing 11.0.2`).
- There is **no** error message. Also java -verbose did not provide anything suspicious (at least to me).
- I have tried `java -Dprism.verbose=true -Dprism.order=sw` and `java -Dprism.verbose=true` and did not see anything suspicious.
- I have tried it on a different machine running macOS and a fresh Java installation with the same results.
- **Update:** I found a bug report which might be related: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8236953

**Environments where the issue DOES exists:**

- macOS Java 11.0.6
- macOS Java 11.0.7
- macOS OpenJDK 11.0.6 (released 15. January 2020)
- macOS Java 13.0.2

**Environments where the issue *does not* exist:**

- macOS Java 11.0.2
- macOS OpenJDK 11.0.5
- macOS OpenJDK 12.0.1
- Windows Java 13.0.2
- macOS Java 14.0.1

**Expected behaviour:**

[image: expected behaviour]

**Behaviour on affected configurations**

[image]

Comment: Can you include the JavaFX version you are using in each case? Or is it always 11.0.2?

Comment: A call to `com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion();` gives "11.0.2+1" - the version I used in the Maven dependencies. Its the same in all cases. I believe it is this bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8236953 . I have just checkt that the issue does not occur with OpenJDK 12.0.1+22". However I had an issue with 12.0.2.  I would like to add a comment to the Java Bug 8236953 that it should fix it in 11.0.x too (being an LTS) (I believe the devs are aware of this).

Comment: Ok, the bug (see also https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236953) has been fixed two days ago, so you might get it with the next JavaFX 14-ea in a few days. Also, most of the bug fixes are back ported to JavaFX 11 LTS, so it might get back ported for the next version (11.0.6 was just released).

Comment: Hi Jose. I believe the bug is quite severe. Any swing up that was wrapped in SwingNode will no longer run on macOS when some used the current version of the only LTS - 11.0.6. Also I could not download 11.0.2 from Oracle anymore (did not find it). Java 11 has to be fixed and I believe they should to it soon. I wanted to leave a message below that bug (seeing that it was set to resolved), but I did not find a way to the bug tracker. Where do I have to register to file bugs? Anyway: thanks for looking at this. Maybe you can drop them a note.

Comment: Indeed, the severity of the bug has been set to `P2`, which is quite high (P1 is the highest). The bug was caused by JDK-8144125 that was fixed in JDK 13 and back ported to 11.0.6. The fix has already been applied to the Java 14 repository (not to OpenJFX), so you will need to wait to use the next JDK 14 early access version, and wait until they back port it to Java 11 LTS, or use versions lower than 11.0.6 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase11-5116896.html). Anyway, these type of fixes are quickly back ported.

Comment: Note: The issue is still present in Java 11.0.7. According to the bug database it is fixed in 11.0.8.

Comment: I can report the bug was fixed in 11.0.8!